# Launch Chrome in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, google-chrome

I'm launching Chrome from an Android App and I want this looks like I'm not leaving the app... for this I do launch chrome from an Intent in this way:

```
public void onClickApp(View view){
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
startActivity(intent);
}
```

But I don't know how to hide the top bar, also would be great to start it "on private". There's a way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you should use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) instead.

Comment: I can not use a WebView, because this uses a very old version of the renderer, and the web app does not run properly... And I don't want use a ChromeView or experiments like that because are not ready for production.

Comment: Have you come up with a solution yet? I'm trying to achieve the same thing ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't be possible. The only way Chrome for Android can be put in a fullscreen mode is use the Fullscreen API: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/fullscreen/

However this requires user interaction to get the UI in fullscreen mode, which isn't quite what you want.

The WebView now uses Chrome as the rendering engine in KitKat: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best chance is to use ChromeView or Chromium-View (i did use the last, but the project has been deleted by its author), good luck!